Is it possible to work on the same Notebook, at the same time, from VScode and JupyterLab?
work: read / write / run the .ipynb file
I have searched around and couldn't find anything conclusive.

Yes. I figured out how, with some caveats, so I document it here for others to use/complain/improve.
Environment: Linux running Jupyterlab and "remote VSCode".
"remote VSCode": I have a light vscode installed in my computer but everything runs in the 'remote' computer, which is the same as the one running the JupyterLab server. You just need proper SSH connection to that 'remote' computer. I think this is irrelevant, but just in case I mention it.

Steps:
This picture may help understand the process.

1. On Jupyterlab, open Master_Notebook (called Jupy_Code in the images)  and choose a kernel.
Notebook and kernel are up and running.

2. On VScode, open a new notebook connected to the same kernel that Jupyter is using for Master_Notebook.
You can do this easily with the extension Jupyter PowerToys
If you click on the second icon, it will open a new notebook connected to that kernel


At this point, each editor has a notebook connected to the same kernel. Variables and whatever you run is seen by both notebooks.
But we also want to 'see' the Master_Notebook, right?

3. In VSCode, open the Master_Notebook and set it as read-only.
View > Command Palette, type read-only

So in VSCode you should have now 2 notebooks. One for reading (the Master_notebook) and the other for writing/running.

Note the lock on the Notebook name on the left side.
You can query/inspect/work the Master_Notebook with tools like Github Copilot / Codeium, do some experiments in the local notebook, and when you are happy with the code, paste it in JupyterLab > Master_Notebook.

Each editor has some strengths that the other doesn't have (not interested in debating here). With this setup, I try to combine them and use each one when I please.
Critic / Comments / Improvements are welcome.

FAQ:
Q: Can I do the same in OS_name ?
A: I don't know. If you try, feel to add another answer or tell me to add here the answer.
--
Q: Can both editors write on the same notebook?
A:
short: You cannot have VSCode and Jupyterlab writing to the same notebook while the other has the file opened.
long: While it is technically possible (Jupyterlab has some extensions for collaborative editing) I wanted a simple solution.
